# Distribution of relative number of fission fragments versus mass number for uranium

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, binding-energy, subatomic

For a fission of U-235 the fission fragments have a plot roughly shown below:
[image]

Is there any basic logic( undergraduate level ) with which we can anticipate this curve?

Imho the fission yield curve should have been this below one, [image]
as this corresponds to more nuclei being formed which have higher binding energy per nucleon, and hence higher stability. But that's incorrect.

Can anyone please answer this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Well, if U-238 splits into two pieces, it needs to be pretty symmetric around mass 119 since one will be heavier and one lighter...

Comment: Thank you so much, it does make the plot very sensible.

Comment: @JonCuster why higher energy fission produces a single peaked curve though?